# How to bind to a viewmodel instead of a page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My problem is with the viewcell, the OnDelete command is not found due to it being of the IssueModel class, I've attempted to change the binding-context of the Listview, but that doesn't change anything except the above binding.

Is there any way to change the binding context of the viewcell so I don't have to put the command into to IssueModel? I've attempted the below solution but I get an error

"Invalid markup extension: expected type is object, actual type is Issuepagemodel"

```
      xmlns:pageModels="clr-namespace:ASFT.PageModels;assembly=ASFT"

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}" SeparatorColor="#444444" RowHeight="90" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}" RefreshCommand="{Binding PullRefreshCommand}" >
        <ListView.Behaviors>
        <helperMethods:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemSelected" 
                                          Command="{Binding OnSelectedIssueCommand}" 
                                          Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell x:Name="Stalin">
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="Hitler" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDelete, Source={pageModels:IssueListPageModel}}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding SeverityImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="70"/>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding StatusImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="60"/>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" YAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Bold, Medium"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Created, Converter={StaticResource DateToTextConverter}}" YAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Medium"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" YAlign="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Small"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Did you try using relativeSource or elementName in the binding?

Comment: Don't know what those are, so maybe. Maybe not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be quite easy, if I understand your problem.

Set your page's `BindingContext` to your `ViewModel` that contains a `Command` with the next name "MyRootLevelCommand".

Name your root UI element:

```
<Grid x:Name="root"> .. </Grid>
```

Let's assume that within this `Grid` you have a `ListView` and you want to bind a `Command` from the page viewmodel to each item in the ListView:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference root}, Path=BindingContext.MyRootLevelCommand}" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. As I don't want to access the root. I want to acess the pagemodel. Not the codebehind page.

Comment: The code above is example of accessing BindingContext (ViewModel) of a Page. Code-behind  is not involved at all.

Comment: Oh wow. Works perfectly. I have no idea how it works, I thought that was supposed  to go the code-behind. As doing a normal binding and just using the name of the command, it gets into the pagemodel in normal cases. (Not this though, as the viewcell goes to the IssueModel this time) BUT now it works. Could you explain how to bind it to code-behind page too? Not that I need and would never need to as that is stupid when using MVVM, just that I want to understand your solution. THANK YOU by the way.

Comment: The official documentation is nicely covering this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics Glad to help!

Comment: Regarding "bind it to code-behind page", usually you use events in this case, as multiple binding contexts are not supported out of the box.