# Getting the selected item from ItemTemplate in seperate file MVVM Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have the PageView which is defined like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Fuse.ViewTemplates;assembly=Fuse"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Fuse.Views.JoinPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="Games near your area .. "
             VerticalOptions="Start"
             HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
             VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelcetedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
              RowHeight="150" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <view:CardViewTemplate/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and the CardTemplateView defined like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fuse.ViewTemplates.CardViewTemplate"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fuse"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Fuse.ViewModels"
             x:Name="CardView"
             >

    <Frame IsClippedToBounds="True"
         HasShadow="True"
         BackgroundColor="White" >
        <Frame.OutlineColor>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
                  Android="Gray"
                  iOS="Gray"/>
        </Frame.OutlineColor>
        <Frame.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Android="7" iOS="7"/>
        </Frame.Margin>
        <Frame.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Android="10" iOS="5"/>
        </Frame.Padding>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">


                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <Button Text="Join" 

                            BackgroundColor="LawnGreen"  BorderRadius="10" BorderWidth="10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    </Button>
                </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

What i want to do is bind the Button to a Command in viewmodel and pass the commandParameter to get the Item in the ListView corresponding to the Grid (aka Button) . This is a custom List Template which the ListView uses , it has a Button inside of it which when clicked should return the SelectedItem in the parent .

I hope I was clear .

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to a viewmodel instead of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674625/how-to-bind-to-a-viewmodel-instead-of-a-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way would be to paste the ContentView into your ContentPage. Then your page needs a name and you can bind:

```
<Button Text="Join" Command="{Binding ElementName=PageName, Path=ViewModel.Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
BackgroundColor="LawnGreen"  BorderRadius="10" BorderWidth="10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    </Button>
```

The other way is to put the command in your CardViewModel (or whatever class you store in CardList) and just assing the command from ContentPageViewModel.

Another way is to add DependencyPropery to your ConentView to store your command.

Comment: If I bind the CommandParameter like you did I get the whole ViewModel returned . I want to return the item corresponding to the ListView so i can see what is its ID and manipulate with it . Unfortunately i can't do that with this